# Enabling CORS On Individual Endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, cors, rest

I have a rest API that has many endpoints to get and post data. I was wondering if it was possible to change from which origins a particular endpoint will allow to interact with. Below you can see that I have the standard CORS enabled throughout the entire app:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});
```

But I want to be able to change CORS properties of the individual endpoints:

```
app.get('/api/blocks/length', (req, res) => {
  res.json(blockchain.chain.length);
});
```

How can this be done? Some insight will mean the world to me.

Comment: `const cors = require('cors'); app.get('/api/blocks/length', cors(), (req, res) => {});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you pass to `app.use` is a middleware function. Let’s break it out to keep things in bite size components.

```
const cors_middleware = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
};
```

(This is wheel reinvention though, you could just use the `cors` module from NPM)

Then you get get your original effect like so:

```
app.use(cors_middleware);
```

Now look at the definition of `get`:

> ```
> app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])
> ```

It takes a list of one or more callbacks.

So you can put your middleware there:

```
app.get('/api/blocks/length', cors_middleware, (req, res) => {
  res.json(blockchain.chain.length);
});
```

Comment: I see. So I can define more than one middleware and use it in the endpoints that it's necessary?